# Can I make CSS written for safari on OS X work in chrome for windows?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I understand both browsers use webkit but when I display a form in safari for OS X the input checkboxes are lined up perfectly in a div.

If I go to chrome then the checkboxes are all over the place.

I was wondering if there was CSS code that could ensure it's lined up perfectly in both browsers? It's not just the checkboxes that are out of line, it's all of the inputs.

Chrome on windows is version 47
Safari on OS X is version 9

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Thank You

```
                <div style="position:relative;text-align:left;top: 15px;left: 193px;">
                <?php echo form_label('Head:','head'); ?><?php echo form_checkbox(array('name'=>'head','type'=>'checkbox','value'=>'1')); ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do for some cross-browser compatibility is not use any kind of absolute positioning.

From your description, it seems like you have the width of the text inputs as a fixed amount, but the container can't hold both the checkboxes and the text inputs.

Maybe set the inputs to `width: calc(100% - #px);`.

Comment: I'll try that. I should have added some of my code. I just made the edit in my post. I am using relative positioning for everything right now. I will try the calc(100%-#px) though

Comment: Just a quick note about `width: calc(100% - #px)`, don't forget the spaces before and after the`-`. For some reason, it won't work without that exact syntax. Also, replace the `#` with a number of course.

Comment: Applying that to the inputs did sort of help. It did make everything match on both browsers. but it unaligned them. I think I will just modify their positions from here since they should be reflected appropriately on both browsers. Thanks!